# Replace an item in list if it starts with a precise character

Tags: python-3.x

I am fairly new to python and have a task to solve.
I have a list that is made of strings made of hexadecimal numbers. I want to replace some items with '0', if they do not start with the right characters.
So, for example, I have

```
List = ['0800096700000000', '090000000000025d', '0b0000000000003c', '0500051b014f0000']
```

and I want, say, to only have the data that starts with "0b" and "05", and I want to replace the others by "0".

For now, I have this:

```
multiplex = ('0b', '05')
List = ['0800096700000000', '090000000000025d', '0b0000000000003c', '0500051b014f0000']
List = [x for x in List if x.startswith(multiplex)]
```

This gives me the following result:

```
['0b0000000000003c', '0500051b014f0000']
```

Although I would like the following result:

```
['0', '0', '0b0000000000003c', '0500051b014f0000']
```

I cannot index the specific item I wish to change because the actual data is way too large for that...

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `if/else` to determine what to return, not if a value should be in the list.

```py
my_list = ['0800096700000000', '090000000000025d', '0b0000000000003c', '0500051b014f0000']

multiplex = ('0b', '05')

my_new_list = [x if x.startswith(multiplex) else '0' for x in my_list]

print(my_new_list)

'''' Sample Output
['0', '0', '0b0000000000003c', '0500051b014f0000']

''''
```

Answer (score 1):

Your multiplex strings are too long, so a single character string does not start with 2 characters. Try `if x.startswith(multiplex) or len(str(x)) < 2 and x.startswith("0")` or `if x.startswith(multiplex) or str(x) == "0"`

Comment: Since I don't know, if there are other 1 character strings, I added "and x.startswith("0")" in the first line of code

Answer (score 0):

`List = [x if x.startswith(multiplex) else '0' for x in List]`